# RadRotator not resizing on browser resize

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, telerik

I'm currently trying to resize this control on browser resize.
I tried to look on the forums before asking. I found a Javascript function ( which is not working unfortunately).

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

window.onresize = function()    
{    
    var rotatorElement = document.getElementById("ContentPlaceHolder1_RadRotator1" + "_Div");    
    rotatorElement.RadResize(); 
}

</script>
```

**Error : RadResize Null or undefined.**

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 0):

Hey Arnaud Add this script in your aspx page and your problem would be solved:

```
script type="text/javascript">    
window.onresize = function()     
{     
    var rotatorElement = document.getElementById("<%= RadRotator1.ClientID %>" + "_Div");     
    rotatorElement.RadResize();  
}     
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you but i still have the same error : RadResize: object null or undefined...

Comment: Getting a reference to a script control is done through $find(), not $get(). You can then try $find().repaint(), but I don't think it will work. Take a look at the KB above.

Answer (score 0):

Hey Arnaud You can easily achieve your goal by specifying fixed layout for the table.

Here is the sample code:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">  
    <table border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="table-layout: fixed">  
        <tr> 
            <td style="width: 100%">  
                <radR:RadRotator ID="RadRotator1" runat="server" TransitionType="Scroll" ContentFile="http://rss.msnbc.msn.com/id/3033655/device/rss/rss.xml" DataMember="item" Height="130px" Width="100%">  
                    <FrameTemplate> 
                        <div class="NewsList">  
                            <p> 
                                <strong><a href="<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"link") %>" target="_blank">  
                                    <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"title") %> 
                                </a></strong>  
                                <br /> 
                                <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"pubDate") %> 
                            </p> 
                            <p> 
                                <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"description") %> 
                            </p> 
                        </div> 
                    </FrameTemplate> 
                </radR:RadRotator> 
            </td> 
        </tr> 
    </table> 

    <script language="Javascript" type="text/javascript">  
    <!--  
    var RadRotator1=<%= RadRotator1.ClientID %>;  
    window.onresize=function() {  
        var rotatorElement = document.getElementById("<%= RadRotator1.ClientID %>" + "_Div");  
        rotatorElement.RadResize();  
    };  
    //--> 
    </script> 

</form>
```